# Load geographical data administrative boundaries for Europe by levels

Tags: openstreetmap, administrative-boundaries

How can I load all administrative boundaries by levels for Europe in coordinates?

I need .osm dates, but not all data inside Europe, just administrative boundaries. I import .osm for Europe in PostGIS base and by filter 'administrative' read data, but I am not sure is it right query.

Can I read those data from natural-earth and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NUTS** (EuroStat) GIS data is available here:

(NUTS = Nomenclature of territorial units for statistics)

http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/gisco_Geographical_information_maps/popups/references/administrative_units_statistical_units_1

> The NUTS classification (Nomenclature of territorial units for
>   statistics) is a hierarchical system for dividing up the economic
>   territory of the EU for the purpose of :
>
> ```
> The collection, development and harmonisation of EU regional statistics.
> Socio-economic analyses of the regions.
> ```
>
> http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/nuts_nomenclature/introduction

Comment: The actual data can be downloaded here at the time of writing: http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units - non-commercial use only so not suitable for inclusion in OpenStreetMap (or any other dataset that allows commercial use.)